Coldfusion running Node and Puppeteer
I have a project that takes an HTML file and using Chrome headless it converts that HTML into a PDF. That all works great, the problem is that I want to be able to save that HTML file as a JPG thumbnail. I know you can do it using Puppeteer but I'm not sure how to get Puppeteer to execute using CFEXECUTE as Puppeteer is run from the command line like this:
node testcase1.js

testcase1.js holds all the puppeteer code. If I run it directly from the command line it works perfectly.
I've tried using a cfexecute in various ways:
<cfexecute name="node.exe" arguments="testcase1.js">

<cfexecute name="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" arguments="testcase1.js">

but nothing happens, the page doesn't even error. I've tried adding an output variable to see any errors and it's just blank.
Can anyone offer any advice to get this working?

You need to use absolute url of the testcase1.js file like C:/Users/.../testcase1.js not relative url
<cfexecute name="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
arguments="C:\Users\...\...\testcase1.js" ✅
timeout="60" 
variable="execution" 
outputFile = "C:\Temp\output.txt" 
errorFile = "C:\Temp\errors.txt" >

replace ... with your actual path
I've added some other important attributes like timeout 60s, if you don't want just remove it
